# Buttons and bold text in bot.sendMessage

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

help me understand what the problem is.
Why are the buttons (menuOptions) not displayed?

```
if (text === '/start') {
                ust[chatId] = 0;
                bot.sendMessage(chatId, `${msg.from.first_name}, <b>Добро пожаловать</b> ✌️\n\nДоступные возможности:`, {
                    parse_mode: "HTML",
                    menuOptions
                })
            }
```

Code menuOptions:

```
module.exports = {
    menuOptions: {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
            inline_keyboard: [
                [{text: 'Списки', callback_data: '/list'}],
                [{text: 'Частые вопросы', callback_data: '/quests'}, {text: 'Распространенные проблемы', callback_data: '/problems'}]
            ]
        })
    }
```

node-telegram-bot-api on Node JS

I tried many ways, remade the menuOptions structure, as soon as I did not insert it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code specifies `menuOptions` key-value pair in the `options` parameter of the `sendMessage` method. What you need to do is directly use `reply_markup` key.

```js
const { menuOptions } = require('./path/to/menu_options');

if (text === '/start') {
    ust[chatId] = 0;
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, `${msg.from.first_name}, <b>Добро пожаловать</b> ✌️\n\nДоступные возможности:`, {
        parse_mode: "HTML",
        reply_markup: menuOptions.reply_markup
    })
}
```

If you want to use other properties than just `reply_markup` in the `menuOptions` object, javascript [spread operator](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es-next/javascript-object-spread/) might help:

```js
{
    parse_mode: 'HTML',
    ...menuOptions
}
```